# Some curiosity about HMAC

Tags: hmac

1. Is the probability of distinguishing HMAC from a random oracle is the same as the probability of forging HMAC?
2. Can we say that the following statement is trivial?

   $\Pr[\text{Forging $\operatorname{HMAC}_k(m)$}] \geq \Pr[\text{Forging $\operatorname{HMAC}_{f(m)}(m)$}]$

   where $f(\cdot)$ is a random oracle and $k$ is a random number.
3. Can we use equality in the above statement?

This is not a homework exercise. I think they are trivial but I am afraid if I am wrong.

Comment: Depends on the properties of $m$ and if $m$ could be known, of course.

Comment: When you use the technical term ‘random oracle’, that suggests you are modeling an _adversary_ as an algorithm with access to the random oracle.  But in that case, part (2) of your question doesn't make sense, because forgery is trivial for such an adversary: there are no secrets from the adversary in computing $\operatorname{HMAC}_{f(m)}(m)$.  Maybe you meant _where $f$ is a uniform random function known only to the user_, in which case the equation is obviously true—it's as if the user has _a secret key for every message_, so it can't be easier to forge than for just one secret key.

Comment: For part (1), it sounds like you might really mean to ask whether PRF security is the same as MAC security, if I read ‘random oracle’ as ‘uniform random function’.  _In general_, the answer is no: if $m \mapsto F_k(m)$ is a good MAC or a good PRF, then $m \mapsto F_k(m) \mathbin\| 1$ is still a good MAC because it resists forgery but it's a bad PRF because it's trivially distinguishable from a uniform random function.  But we conjecture that HMAC (with a reasonable choice of hash function) is a good PRF _and so_ it must also be a good MAC—its PRF security can't be higher than its MAC security.

Comment: On the other hand, maybe I guessed wrong, and maybe you're actually asking about the HMAC construction's _random oracle indifferentiability_, which is a slightly different kettle of fish.  (Obviously, all this depends on _instantiating_ HMAC with a reasonable choice of hash function like SHA-256, and not, say, 2-pass Snefru.)

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage. Thanks for the comments. Do you know what the probability of forging HMAC-SHA256 with 128 key is?

Comment: @Reza Well, it depends on how much effort you spend at it.  But, generally, HMAC-SHA256 is expected to be a reasonably good PRF, so the only two strategies are (a) guessing the tag online, which works on each trial with probability $1/2^{256}$, or (b) guessing the key offline, with probability $1/2^{128}$ for a single guess, although there's a batch advantage to a multi-target attack which costs an expected $2^{128}\!/t$ HMAC-SHA256 evaluations to find the first of $t$ keys.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage thanks for the info. I did not get what you mean by $2^{128}/t$ HMAC-SHA256. In way that I read this, it means larger $t$ needs less effort which is not correct.

Comment: @Reza You read it right.  There is a batch advantage to a generic key search like this: you can find the first of $t$ keys in about $2^{128}\!/t$ cost (not $2^{128}$ as a single-target attack would be), and _all_ of $t$ keys in about $2^{128}$ cost (not $2^{128} t$ as $t$ independent single-target attacks would be).